# Create .mat v7.3 files from Python using hdf5storage

Tags: python, hdf5, mat

Is there any way to create .mat v7.3 files from Python? I have been managed to create hdf5 files from Python but not in converting them into .mat v7.3 files. 
I found a package called [hdf5storage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.1) but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? I have never used .mat files before, but maybe its something unrelated to that

Comment: Actually the problem is solved for me. I am just providing a brief if it might be helpful. using scipy.io we can create v7.0 mat files using python. But it won’t work for v7.3 mat files as they are typically hdf5 files. So I used another package called hdf5storge (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.1) and try to produce the example in http://pythonhosted.org//hdf5storage/introduction.html#making-the-data . But this didn't work as the given variable names are not Unicode characters. This example needs a correction with appending u before each variable (Ex: u'f': 'hello', )...

Comment: This correction is suggested to me by the writer of this package :- https://github.com/frejanordsiek

Comment: You don't need to use hdf5storage, h5py sufices. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195457/how-to-write-mat-v7-3-files-using-h5py/78195458#78195458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example (requires Python >= 2.6 with the NumPy and h5py >= 2.1 packages):

```
import hdf5storage # get code on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.3

matcontent = {}
matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = [10, 50, 20] # each key must be a unicode string
hdf5storage.write(matcontent, '.', 'test.mat', store_python_metadata=False, matlab_compatible=True)
```

In Matlab:

[image]

---

If you want to have a matrix instead of a cell array in Matlab:

```
import hdf5storage # get code on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdf5storage/0.1.3
import numpy as np

matcontent = {}
matcontent[u'some_numbers'] = np.array([10, 50, 20]) # each key must be a unicode string
hdf5storage.write(matcontent, '.', 'test2.mat', matlab_compatible=True)
```

[image]

As you will notice, the second example is much faster (>x10).

---

More generally, refer to the documentation for the [data storage matching](http://pythonhosted.org/hdf5storage/storage_format.html):

[image]